# Using scipy curve_fit to fit exponential function to data, but all y data is near 0 in plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I've been using this tutorial (https://swharden.com/blog/2020-09-24-python-exponential-fit/) to fit an exponential curve on my data (see pastebin for data: https://pastebin.com/DrEvJcRC). I adapted the Input to use my own data and I changed the function from negative exponential `(m * np.exp(-t * x) + b)`
to
positive exponential `(m * np.exp(t * x) + b)`.

This is my code (adapted from the tutorial):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy


# read data
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:/Users/HP/OneDrive/Bachelor/Segmentierung/Excel/1_new.csv', sep=";")
print(df)

x = df["x"]
y = df["y"]

# plot original
plt.plot(x, y, '.')
plt.title("Original Data")
plt.show()


def monoexp(x, m, t, b):
    return m * np.exp(t * x) + b

# perform the fit
# start with values near those we expect

params, cv = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(monoexp, x, y)
m, t, b = params
sampleRate = 20_000 # Hz
tauSec = (1 / t) / sampleRate

# determine quality of the fit
squaredDiffs = np.square(y - monoexp(x, m, t, b))
squaredDiffsFromMean = np.square(y - np.mean(y))
rSquared = 1 - np.sum(squaredDiffs) / np.sum(squaredDiffsFromMean)
print(f"R² = {rSquared}")

# plot the results
plt.plot(x, y, '.', label="data")
plt.plot(x, monoexp(x, m, t, b), '--', label="fitted")
plt.title("Fitted Exponential Curve")
plt.show()

# inspect the parameters
print(f"Y = {m} * e^({t} * x) + {b}")
print(f"Tau = {tauSec * 1e6} µs")
```

However when I tried to plot the fitted function all the y data is concentrated near y = 0, despite the data not being centered near zero in the raw data.

[original data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ss5Fg.png)
[fitted curve + original data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Z1sn.png)

I'm not sure if this is a problem with matplotlib or my data. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:
Here the original arrays:

```
y = np.array([[  50.265654   50.481338   55.598281   57.875762   54.32182    58.760685
   62.847534   64.28961    57.020572   72.1828     57.467019   62.230506
   67.540995   64.496286   54.763321   70.058298   70.710515   58.604998
   63.856038   71.711142   61.436699   69.918246   71.709434   72.019284
   71.667271   64.667837   73.15604    72.78848    75.194899   73.362767
   65.633833   76.527694   79.975514   66.31111    83.238201   86.12114
   61.883045   83.874603   68.157062   91.044078   92.729386   71.74222
   86.349847   82.8457     94.123932   89.738375   47.495947   78.255301
   98.873243   94.74139    93.019812  100.313886   97.69019    57.750244
   68.613443   37.156953  104.759545   85.397733  102.651581   99.332523
   66.748191  100.283648   84.807827   83.60035   109.183196   85.638829
   97.114549   99.870095   95.865177   95.974271   77.56365    95.365718
   79.186443   85.08403    76.981884   92.026004   90.356532   97.741741
   90.561301   95.034609   86.457017   93.39508    90.173374   92.576365
   96.131347   97.231791   95.589212   96.561979   94.905649   96.565916
   93.393454   99.992579   98.07305    93.475501  101.344676   98.577551
   97.309664   99.832354   96.305865  107.564353  100.852842  102.705253
   99.991087  100.500039   92.741113  105.655507  112.564399  113.391128
  112.92131   108.758485  116.600566  119.832142  116.127415   96.076771
  118.041184  121.801249  104.471811  119.362042  125.783554   99.582637
  121.588023  127.001352  142.354073  129.378792  122.716748  123.295855
  125.646691  117.353543  129.07801   133.94258   124.015839  125.661787
  130.53109   144.816005  157.213145  135.520705  149.981018  145.649621
  152.043158  151.030789  172.135762  157.441351  156.543511  136.303031
  166.656986  160.05244   161.973895  163.219232  170.589712  167.537767
  169.779851  194.229855  170.166431  174.551329  205.846669  188.975028
  206.772085  212.799242  193.089462  220.674931  225.05487   222.929436
  235.62132   257.330955  249.044577  231.147388  277.336486  257.839554
  269.695485  263.06116   271.412341  265.298246  271.612072  275.421131
  290.819824  267.474925  268.129235  261.022281  268.555814  269.902072
  274.178234  278.662213  291.951716  274.587357  279.547121  273.842799
  287.096126  301.781704  318.724333  320.13565   319.823382  305.842588
  323.785279  312.432472  360.068566  340.44523   357.468329  397.867687
  372.629412  373.711258  388.787463  401.839697  403.886104  407.850298
  414.755803  410.143675  407.997144  418.170715  446.555237  436.598994
  443.822001  453.202132  457.683222  473.140737  486.566587  507.351791
  521.557097  491.379094  523.612526  526.795454  553.596441  556.339232
  560.420248  564.853146  560.541646  574.501924  575.880492  580.008003
  606.287027  593.064523  575.563008  630.483781  614.198263  650.491796
  624.158124  666.845517  679.263829  663.266799  671.248458  655.239931
  669.626968  695.610041  667.202116  706.391511  711.907568  717.474155
  726.638     727.172115  758.956431  759.93291   764.690474  774.672464
  757.418492  822.346932  788.690474  794.585579  815.187357  828.10081
  810.168531  806.578016  833.373597  825.524955  895.056386  868.329793
  865.217297  892.069431  901.155111  841.722724  912.566196  906.663263
  911.161195  926.260885  891.846802  952.404458  968.076496  949.08048
  983.608895  975.126401 1020.251247  991.357126 1030.692856 1076.355363
 1057.721679 1100.199617 1068.971153 1109.204842 1123.111699 1136.594802
 1110.202018 1186.288809 1171.616713 1174.268427 1172.328883 1209.430644
 1213.274975 1226.917626 1243.912662 1258.744995 1284.971544 1286.015899
 1327.096185 1331.784306 1371.597679 1370.215724 1431.747674 1468.234523
 1476.391553 1466.01931  1444.764882 1472.96347  1511.162425 1551.551958
 1593.354289 1554.588089 1542.742428 1586.901403 1573.936749 1726.079181
 1619.650554 1657.632404 1761.770143 1719.361989 1703.11686  1747.136463
 1773.522743 1778.767987 1783.531536 1741.582718 1850.804924 1808.78412
 1790.434519])
```

```
x = np.array([[  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18
  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36
  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54
  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72
  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90
  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108
 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126
 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144
 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162
 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180
 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198
 199 200 201 202 203 204 205 206 207 208 209 210 211 212 213 214 215 216
 217 218 219 220 221 222 223 224 225 226 227 228 229 230 231 232 233 234
 235 236 237 238 239 240 241 242 243 244 245 246 247 248 249 250 251 252
 253 254 255 256 257 258 259 260 261 262 263 264 265 266 267 268 269 270
 271 272 273 274 275 276 277 278 279 280 281 282 283 284 285 286 287 288
 289 290 291 292 293 294 295 296 297 298 299 300 301 302 303 304 305 306
 307 308 309 310 311 312 313 314 315 316 317 318 319 320 321 322 323 324
 325 326 327 328 329 330 331])
```

yours sincerely
Cornelius

Comment: what are the values of R2? looks like is only the last points of the fit that is going out of scale. If you zoom in this should be still ok If you post an array of original x and y values maybe I can try to fit my self

Comment: You can sometimes get a better fit with normalized data, i.e. divide your input by the mean or maximum of the input

Comment: Hey thanks alot,
my Output is:
R² = -1.226684844985675e+254
Y = 1.6238054496228455e-13 * e^(1.0000000025494526 * x) + -3.9063452077163774e+118
Tau = 49.99999987252736 µs

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html#scipy.optimize.curve_fit) says that if no initial value `p0` is provided, all parameters are initialized as `1`. This is orders of magnitudes off from the actual values in your example. Also note that due to the huge range of exponential functions even on small intervals, this is generally only going to work with a good initializations of your parameters.

From the plot it looks like we could assume that `m` is roughly `1`, and `b` is roughly `0`. What is left is `t`, and if you consider that the exponential function should be around `y=2000` at `x=300`, we could start out with `t=0.1` or `t=0.01` (as an approximation of `log(2000)/300`). If we plug this into your `curve_fit` as `p0=[1, 0.01, 0]` we get a more reasonable result:

[image]

Finally I should add that I'd give it some more though if a *least squares* fit (which is what `curve_fit` uses) is really what you want for an exponential function, or whether there might be other alternatives to find a working approximation.

Answer (score 0):

The flawr's answer is very good. In fact there is no need for more answers.

Nevertheless I would like to add a comment (too long to be edited in the comments section).

The method of nonlinear regression used in your sofware is iterative. It is well known that starting the iterative calculus requiers to set some initial values to the parameters. That is judiciously mentioned in the flawr's answer with an empirical approach to guess initial values.

This is very important because if the initial values are too far from the unknown correct values the iterative calculus might fail.

Of course all would be easier with a not iterative method which doesn't require to guess initial values. Such a method exists as shown below.

[image]

Numerical example with your data :

[image]

Comparing to non linear regression (iterative method) one obtain :

a=-2.91212 ; b=35.547425 ; c=0.012030 ; RMSE=30.050141 (Root Mean Square Error).

With this data the fitting is the same for the both methods. One cannot distinguish any difference between the two respective blue curves on the above graph.

FOR INFORMATION :

The above method is a linear regression wrt a linear integral equation to which the exponential equation is solution :

[image]

In the numerical calculus the Sk are the values of the integral computed by numerical integration.

Ref.: https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales